# https Redirect Oauth 2 URL on http page

Tags: javascript, http, https, oauth-2.0

I have a http home page on which we have a div layover on which we have the google sign in button. When we click on the sign in button we have set the redirect url to be https. However the javascript call window.open does not open the pop up https url on the http page. It works on https parent page. Any idea why this is so and how we can fix it?

Is this policy from Google's side or some mixed content policy is kicking in here ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it is logically as the parent can set values on form in child popup so in this case HTTP page can set values in HTTPS page and this is not acceptable, I think you have to redirect to google page not use popup and you can use "state" OAuth paramater to store state of user on your app